# Will Professor Birch offer the Gen 2 starter Pokémon without beating the Elite 4?

Tags: pokemon-third-generation, pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

It is pretty well-documented that in Pokémon Emerald, if you have completed the Hoenn Pokédex (200 Pokémon logged) you can speak to Professor Birch to get **one** of the Gen 2 starters.

I want to collect all three of the Gen 2 starters and trade them over to FireRed. (Without purchasing a Pokémon Colosseum game.) I have all of the Hoenn Dex Pokémon on FireRed, so I can reset my Emerald cartridge and then trade them all *back* onto Emerald.

However, if I do that at the first available chance when trading becomes available, will Professor Birch give me a Johto starter? Or are there other conditions that need to be met as well, such as beating the Elite Four?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the only condition is to *complete the Pokédex*, said textually by profesor Birch, so, if you have every Hoenn Pokémon in FireRed and time to transfer them, you will get a Jhoto starter in no time.

Comment: Great! Have you tried it before? If this is a confirmed thing and not just speculation, I'll accept the answer!

Comment: Actually, the post was an speculation, but I’ve searched a bit since then and you have to get the National Dex to have the opportunity to get one of Jhoto starters, which is only given when you complete Elite Four.

Comment: But that won’t be a problem if you can trade in a strong team.